# Frida command not available after installing Frida PIP Python package

Tags: frida

Why is the `frida` command not available on the command line.
After I install Frida by running

```
$ pip install --user frida
```

It looks like the installation was successful, but when I run the `frida` command the system cannot find it.

```
$ frida
frida: command not found
```

Is the Python PIP package for Frida broken?

Answer (score 6):

Frida was split into two PIP packages.

The package `frida` only contains the python bindings, while `frida-tools` also contains the familiar command line tools from earlier releases.
This is explained in [the news post for the 12.0 release](https://frida.re/news/2018/07/12/frida-12-0-released/):

> **CLI tools**
>
> One thing that caused a bit of confusion in the past was the fact that
>   our Python bindings also came with some CLI tools. Frida is a toolkit
>   for building tools, and even though we provide a few sample tools it
>   should be up to you if you want to have them installed.
>
> Up until now this meant anyone building a tool using our Python
>   bindings would end up depending on colorama, prompt-toolkit, and
>   pygments, because our CLI tools happen to depend on those.
>
> Well, that changes now. If you do:
>
> `$ pip install frida`
>
> You will now only get our Python bindings. Nothing more. And this
>   package has zero dependencies.
>
> The CLI tools might still be useful to you, though, so to install
>   those do:
>
> `$ pip install frida-tools`

Answer (score 0):

This might be occuring because you are having a multiple users on your device and the frida binary is loaded onto the other users. Same thing happened to me.
If you do locate frida

`locate frida`

you will possibly find out that frida is installed on the other user bin directory.

Comment: This is not the behavior of `pip`; it will install to the current user's home directory.

Answer (score 0):

install frida-tools

```
pip install frida-tools
```

After this frida will work fine. Worked for me.